# increment a numerical value in a json with jq

Tags: json, regex, bash, jq, inplace-editing

I have a json which looks like this:-

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "version": "20.02.01",
    "tag": "24",
    "abc_version": "20.02",
    "registry": "registry.abc.com",
    "vendor": "greenplanet",
    "apps": [
      {
        "name": "abc-app",
        "version": "20.02.01-16",
        "volumes": [
          "/dev/log:/dev/log"
        ],
        "max_instances": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "xyz-app",
        "version": "2.0.0-2",
        "volumes": [
          "/dev/log:/dev/log"
        ],
        "max_instances": "1"
      }      
    ]
}
```

based on a condition I need to increment the abc-app's or xyz-app's version. At present its at "20.02.01-16" for abc-app and I need to change it to "20.02.01-17". Also I need to increment the tag of the parent app which is "abc"  to "25"
I am able to increment the version with sed but that is not working for me:-

```
./jq -r ".apps" version.json | ./jq -r ".[] | .version" | grep -v '1.0.2' |sed -r 's/([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)(.*)([0-9]+)/echo "\1\2$((\3+1))"/e'
```

I need to increment all the above conditions in-place in json or maybe into a temporary file which I can move to original.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *I need to increment all the above conditions in-place in json or maybe into a temporary file which I can move to original.* `jq` doesn't support in-place editing, so you have to do the latter (Or use something like `sponge` from moreutils).

Comment: This might help: `jq '.tag=(.tag|tonumber)+1' file.json`

Comment: @Cyrus - .tag is supposed to be a string.

Comment: @peak: This might help: `jq '.tag=((.tag|tonumber)+1|tostring)' file.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's define a helper function to perform the incrementation:

```
# return a string
def inc:
  (capture("(?<pre>.*)-(?<post>[0-9]+$)") | "\(.pre)-\( (.post|tonumber) + 1 )")
  // "\(tonumber+1)" ;
```

The remainder of the solution can now be written in two lines, one for each value to be incremented:

```
.tag |= inc
| .apps |= map(if .name == "abc-app" then .version |= inc else . end)
```

### In-place editing

You could use `sponge`, or a temporary file, or ... (see e.g.
`"How can "in-place" editing of a JSON file be accomplished?"`
on jq's [FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ)).

Comment: Getting this error when running inside an AWS codepipeline>>
jq  '.tag |= (capture("(?<pre>.*)-(?<post>[0-9]+$)") | "\(.pre)-\( (.post|tonumber) + 1 )") "\(tonumber+1)"' version.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected QQSTRING_START, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.tag |= (capture("(?<pre>.*)-(?<post>[0-9]+$)") | "\(.pre)-\( (.post|tonumber) + 1 )") "\(tonumber+1)"                                                                                       
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: worked after I included the logic into a file and ran with jq -f jq_logic version.json